# Video doesnt play on desktop browsers all the time

Tags: html, video, autoplay

Video which for some reason doesn't play most of the time on Desktop.

```
<video autoplay loop id="video-background" class="video-bg" poster="assets/images/home-vid.jpg">
  <source  src="/assets/videos/home.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Video shoudl autoplay in loop when page is opened..

I tried on FF, Chrome it play once as Private browsing then it stopped playing again..

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            verticalCentered: true,
            //sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE'],
            afterRender: function () {
                //playing the video
                $('video').get(0).play();
            }
        });


   });
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a JS code to manipulate the DOM like this to play the video when the page is rendered?                                                                                                     
<script>
    document.getElementById('video-background').play();
</script>

Comment: Yes, found bit of script in layout page not home page... but same was working fine few days back and now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add playsinline autoplay muted loop, Chrome dont allow a video to autostart if it'ss not muted
You can try this:

```
<video src="{{ asset('/assets/videos/home.mp4' )}}" muted autoplay loop playsinline></video>
And put this js after that:

window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
  let video = document.querySelector('video[muted][autoplay]');
  try {
    await video.play();
  } catch (err) {
    video.controls = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: I noticed error in consolue pointing to Muted, anyway my video was with audion so i didnt mute it, after adding `muted` its working fine..

Comment: @Learning Please correct my answer if it works :) Thanks